# Spark + Kafka Integration error. NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/internal/connector/SimpleTableProvider

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka 2.5.0 and Spark 3.0.0. I'm trying to import some data from kafka into spark. The following code snippet gives me an erorr:

```
spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "topic1").load()
```

The error I get says

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/internal/connector/SimpleTableProvider
```

Comment: can you try running --verbose option and share the complete log. or spark-submit command also fine?

Answer (score 0):

This error is mainly due to spark-kafka dependency conflicts.

You can check the supporting scala version in maven repository if not yet.

If the error still occurring then you can share more details like the groupId, artifactId along with version.